# Is Every Holomorphic Near an Entire?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $K\subset \mathbb C$ be a closed subset of the complex plane, not necessarily bounded.
 Let $U$ be the interior of $K$.

Let $f:K\to \mathbb C$ be a continuous bounded function, whose restriction to $U$ is holomorphic.

Assume furthermore that for every closed curve $\gamma\subset K$, the integral $\int_\gamma f(z)dz$ vanishes. (this is only relevant if $K$ is not simply connected). If you prefer, you can assume that $K$ is simply connected.

> Can $f$ be uniformly approximated by entire functions?

Comment: Do you know Mergelyan's theorem?

Comment: I don't why some people have voted to close this question! Why?

Comment: @MohammadGhiasi because it is answered by a well known theorem in complex analysis, namely Mergelyan's theorem.

Comment: @StevenGubkin But this theorem just proves the question in the cases which the domain is compact.

Comment: If you are not working on a compact set, then there are counterexamples.  You need some control of the rate of growth of the function.  This area of research has also been extensively developed.

Comment: I have reworded the question, and I vote to keep it open. @Steven Gubkin: you seem to be knowledgeable in the area; if you have an answer to the question as currently worded, I would be curious to hear it.

Comment: I think it is really just a literature search question, which I am not sure is appropriate, so I will just answer in the comments.  In the case of an unbounded domain, one needs an extension of Mergelyan's theorem, namely the Keldysh approximation theorem.  As long as the compliment of $U$ is connected as a subset of the Riemann sphere, this approximation goes through. (My thesis, just completed, was about an $L^2$ version of Mergelyan's theorem in several variables.  So maybe I have just been swimming here so long I think nothing of it... )

Comment: @StevenGubkin One of the hardest things to realize at the end of your PhD is that you're really an expert now. :)

Comment: @StevenGubkin Why don't you write a real answer?

Comment: In addition to the answers given, a literature reference: Dieter Gaier, "Lectures on Complex Approximation", includes Mergelyan's and Arakelyan's theorems, and much more!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is true if $K$ is compact and the complement of $K$ in the Riemann sphere is connected : it is the content of Mergelyan's Theorem on uniform polynomial approximation of holomorphic functions.

**EDIT** If $K$ is only assumed to be closed, this is also true with the additional assumption that $K$ is locally connected at infinity : it is the content of Arakelian's theorem on the uniform approximation of holomorphic functions by entire functions.

It is false in general if the complement of $K$ is not connected : consider $K$ the annulus $\{1/2 \leq |z| \leq 2\}$ and $f(z):=1/z^2$. Then $f$ is continuous on $K$, holomorphic in the interior of $K$, and $\int_\gamma f(z)\, dz=0$ for all closed curve $\gamma$ contained in $K$. However, $f$ cannot be uniformly approximated on $K$ by entire functions $(f_n)$. Indeed, if it were the case, then the functions $g_n(z):=zf_n(z)$ would uniformly approximate $g(z):=zf(z)=1/z$ on $K$. This contradicts the fact that $\int_\mathbb{T} g_n(z)\, dz=0$ for all $n$, whereas $\int_\mathbb{T} g(z) \, dz = 2\pi i \neq 0$. Here $\mathbb{T}$ is the unit circle.

Comment: A natural attempted fix would be to require "for any disc $D$ in $\mathbb{C}$ with $\partial D \subseteq K$ and any holomorphic $g$ on $D$, we have $\int_{\partial D} f(z) g(z) dz=0$." Any idea if the statement is true with that condition?

Comment: I don't understand how this is just Mergelyan's Theorem on uniform polynomial approximation of holomorphic functions. Take the example of the function $f(z)=\sin(z)$, defined on some horizontal strip say $K=\{z\in\mathbb C : Im(z)\in[-1,1]\}$. This function CANNOT be uniformly approximated by polynomials.

Comment: It should be noted that, even if the complement is not connected, we do get approximation by rational functions in much the same way (at least for bounded domains, I have not thought too much about unbounded ones).  In fact, the proof of Mergelyans theorem consists of two steps:  1.  prove that for each $\epsilon$ one can find an open set $U_\epsilon$ containing $K$, and $f_\epsilon$ holomorphic on $U_\epsilon$ such that $\operatorname{max}_{K}|f - f_\epsilon| < \epsilon$  2. Use runge's theorem.

Comment: @AndréHenriques your example cuts the Riemann sphere into two disconnected pieces

Comment: The question is about closed subsets of the complex plane. The question is not about closed subsets of the Riemann sphere. If you prefer, take $f(z)=\sin(z)$ defined on $K=\{z\in\mathbb C: Im(z)\in[-1,1], Re(z)>0\}$. Again, this is not uniformly approximable by polynomials.

Comment: @AndréHenriques The question does not ask for approximation by polynomials, instead by entire functions.  In your case, the entire function $\sin(z)$ works perfectly!

Comment: @AndréHenriques I agree that Mergelyan's theorem by itself is not enough.  In my comments to the OP I misspoke:  it is Arakelian's theorem which I was thinking of.  See here, for instance. http://www.jstor.org/stable/2325151?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @AndréHenriques I assumed that $K$ was compact, thanks for the remarks. As Steven Gubkin mentioned, if $K$ is only assumed to be closed, it follows from Arakelian's approximation theorem. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer : Interesting question. Note that you should replace "circle" by "Jordan curve" in your condition, for otherwise one can consider $K$ a topological annulus around $0$ not containing any circle surrounding its hole and then the $1/z^2$ counterexample works.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer : With the condition "for any Jordan curve $\gamma$ contained in the interior of $K$ and any function $g$ holomorphic in the interior of $K$, we have $\int_\gamma f(z)g(z) \, dz = 0$", I think the statement is true, at least for sufficiently nice compact sets $K$, e.g. if $K$ has finitely many holes. The point here is that this condition ensures that $f$ extends analytically to each hole, so that we can apply Mergelyan's theorem to uniformly approximate $f$ by polynomials.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer : To see that the condition implies analytic extension of $f$, consider for simplicity the case where $K$ is an annulus centered at the origin. Then we can use Cauchy's integral formula to write $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ in $K$. Now let $k$ be any negative integer and apply the condition with $g(z)=z^{-k-1}$ to obtain that $a_k=0$. This shows that the Taylor coefficients with negative indices all vanish, thus $f$ extends analytically to the hole of $K$.

Answer (score 9):

This theorem does not follow in a straightforward way from Mergelyan's theorem, which on its face applies only to bounded domains.

There is, however, a related theorem called Arakelian's theorem which settles the matter.  For completeness:

**Definition**: A "hole" of a closed subset $E$ of $\mathbb{C}$ is any bounded component of the complement of $E$.

**Definition** A set $E$ is Arakelian if $E$ has no holes, and if for every closed disk $D$, the union of all holes of $E \cup D$ is bounded.

**Theorem** Let $E$ be Arakelian. If $f$ is continuous on $E$ and holomorphic on the interior of $E$, then $f$ can be uniformly approximated by entire functions.

A proof deriving this result from Mergelyan's theorem can be found [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2325151?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

---

I would also like to remark that Mergelyan's theorem (while usually stated for polynomial approximation) actually applies to domains with holes as well, if you just allow rational approximation with "poles in the holes".

I would also like to draw attention to how crazy Mergelyan's theorem is.  One consequence is that one can approximate an antiholomorphic function by entire functions on any set without interior.  For instance, one can approximate $\overline{z}$ on the "plus sign" consisting on the interval $[-1,1]$ on the real axis and "$[-i,i]$" on the imaginary axis.  If anyone can explicitly construct such approximating functions, I would be very happy to see them!

Comment: For your "plus sign" approximation, take $f(z) = z^3 g(z^4)$ where $g$ is a polynomial such that $|t^{3/4} (g(t) - t^{-1/2})| < \epsilon$ for $t \in [0,1]$.  Such $g$ can be found using standard numerical approximation methods.  For example, with $\epsilon \approx 0.1$, g(t) = 13.6602896164833+(-295.346171207092+(3061.90100782145+(-16221.4880068369+(48270.4896476068+(-84097.0658600084+(85091.1281127053+(-46285.3324386071+10463.1560731230*t)*t)*t)*t)*t)*t)*t)*t will work.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  That is very insightful.